# Neural Net Activation Function with Numerical, Categorical Output

Tags: keras, neural-network, layer, activation-function

I have a neural network that outputs numeric values, but these values are categorical (e.g., 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1). What would be a good activation function to use for my output layer?

I am wondering this because my output is numerical, but categorical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `softmax` activation function. It is good for things like digit recognition and grouping numbers in a categorical setting. Hopefully this work soft your application!